# Fullcalendar - Hide dates in grid header

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to use a fullcalendar to configure some data that applies to days of the week, but not tied to specific dates. So I want to show a calendar that doesn't include the actual dates in the header, and instead just shows the day of the week

So:

```
Mon, Tue, Wed,  ...
```

instead of

```
Mon 2/1,    Tue 2/2,    Wed 2/3,    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below common configuration for all views..

```
columnFormat: 'ddd', // Or any moment format as you require to show.
```

You also can give [View-Specific-Options](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/).

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    views: {
        basic: {
            columnFormat: 'ddd'
        },
        agenda: {
            columnFormat: 'ddd'
        },
        week: {
            columnFormat: 'ddd'
        },
        day: {
            columnFormat: 'ddd'
        }
    }
});
```

This works for me.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was after.